# Thinking Sphinx indexing non-expired records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indexing, conditional-statements, thinking-sphinx

What would be the best approach to have Thinking Sphinx only index records where Today's date is less than or equal to the record's "expires_at" field?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest approach is adding the following statement to your define_index block:

```
where "expired_at >= NOW()"
```

That's the MySQL version, anyway. PostgreSQL will be pretty similar:

```
where "expired_at >= current_timestamp"
```

Although, I'm no PostgreSQL expert, but hopefully that's close enough to what's needed.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL also accepts the function 'now()'